# How do I upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04?

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I upgrade Ubuntu to 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-ubuntu-to-12-04)

I am using Ubuntu 11 (Ocelot) on my desktop PC, I installed it to run and keep Windows. These days I find I use Ubuntu more and more and Windows less and less. So, now I see Ubuntu 12 is being released real soon, can I update ocelet, or do I have to remove it from my computer and then rinstall Ubuntu 12